# Which objects are atomic in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am looking for a full list of atomic objects in Mathematica (for which `AtomQ` yields `True`).

I know about

```
Symbol
String
Integer
Real
Rational
Complex

SparseArray
BooleanFunction
Graph
```

Are there any others?

ref: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BasicObjects.html

**EDIT:**  Continually adding new symbols from answers to list above.

Comment: I am sure that the developers had their reasons to add more atomic objects to the list (which remained fixed for a long time), perhaps such as better integration of components, efficiency, etc, but if this represents a new development trend, I'd be worried, since keeping the number of elementary and atomic objects small seems (to me anyway) to be one essential ingredient for the true power and consistency of a programming language.

Comment: Why did someone down-vote this?

Comment: Now that you're "back in town" have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears your list needs one more object to be complete:

```
In[520]:= f = BooleanFunction[30, 3];

In[521]:= AtomQ[f]

Out[521]= True
```

Comment: I am curious if there is any programmatic way to get this list (possibly based on some undocumented internal top-level functions), with only the top-level functionality (available to the end-user)?

Comment: @Leonid, I'm also curious, and also tried to do that.  It's not trivial, compare e.g. `AtomQ@SparseArray[]` with `AtomQ@SparseArray[{1->1}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs I think I can explain at least what you observed. For non-trivial atomic heads such as `Rational`, `Complex`, `SparseArray` (those that appear to have elements and not be atomic, the way they are rendered), auto-evaluation happens. For example, `AtomQ[Unevaluated[Rational[1, 2]]]` gives `False`. This auto-evaluation is normally invisible, but you can track it with `On[]`. It does not happen when you supply wrong number or type of arguments, like in `Rational[{1},{2}]`. My guess is that `AtomQ` (as well as some other functions) is internally overloaded on these auto-evaluated forms.

Comment: @leonid I would guess that Rational[1,2] does not auto-evaluate to an atom, but rather the atom is directly constructed in the parse stage.

Comment: @ragfield I really doubt that. First of all, this would be a really bad design, since parsing stage should not be mixed with evaluation stage. Second, if you call `On[]`, you can clearly see the non-trivial trace for `Rational[1,2]`, while nothing for say `Rational[{1},{2}]`. Lastly, if that would be the case, then `AtomQ[Unevaluated[Rational[1, 2]]]` must give `True`, since `Unevaluated` is only effective at run-time (unless, of course, special parsing rules have also been added for `Unevaluated[some atom]`, but that's kind of hard to imagine).

Comment: @ragfield In fact, we can prove that we are dealing with auto-evaluation here, as follows: `Block[{Rational},
 AtomQ[Rational[1, 2]]]` gives `False`. And, this could not be done for all cases at parse-time anyway, without breaking some functional/mettaprogramming features of Mathematica, allowing for example for the code like this: `Rational @@ {1, 2}`, and generally for the  automatic construction of atomic objects from pieces at run-time.

Comment: Leonid is right, could also check the length of expressions returned by `Trace`

Comment: @leonid Fair enough, though the InputForm of Rational (and Complex) appear to be parsed directly to atoms.  I incorrectly assumed the FullForm would behave similarly.

In[162]:= Block[{Complex}, AtomQ[1 + 2 I]]

Out[162]= True

In[164]:= Block[{Rational}, AtomQ[1/2]]

Out[164]= True

Comment: @ragfield Sorry, but your examples are still manifesting the evaluation artifacts, not parsing. Try `Block[{Times, Power, Rational}, AtomQ[1/2]]` - will be False. For the example with `I`, we can not `Block` `I` alas. But calling `On[]` at the start will show the trace. `I` gets auto-evaluated to `Complex[0,1]`, and then there are non-trivial evaluations of `Times` and `Plus`. I don't know why blocking `Complex` (and also `Plus` and `Times`) does not work here, but in any case, what we get is a result of non-trivial evaluation, rather than that being formed during parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we have another one:

```
obj = Graphics`Mesh`Delaunay @ RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]

AtomQ[obj]
```

> ```
> "MeshObject[1]"[2, {10, 21, 12}]
>
> True
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to check my replies on SO (I did check them on Mma.SE).  Are you still using v7?  On v8 this doesn't seem to be atomic.  Did you have to do any other initialization to make this function usable than [``Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[]``](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13596/12)?

Comment: @Szabolcs still on v7, and no, running only the code above is sufficient to produce the given output.

Comment: It must be a difference between v7 and v8 then.  It's a little surprising as I'd expect them to move from composite expressions to optimized atomic representations, not the other way.